# Android - CardView sometimes hide content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm developing an App that use RecyclerView to display a list of products. Everything works fine, but sometimes, some TextViews is not showed inside the CardView. Using Layout Inspector I've noticed that the views are there, but the CardView layout hided the content. Bellow is my code:

card_view_product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewProductImage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewProductName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="Texto"
                android:textColor="@color/black_87"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewProductImage"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewPriceFrom"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="R$"
                android:textColor="@color/black_24"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewProductName"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewPriceTo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="R$"
                android:textColor="@color/faded_orange"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewPriceFrom"/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

content_category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_category">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewProducts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the onBindViewHOlder of my adapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (position>(products.size()-4)){
        parent.loadMoreProducts();
    }
    final ProductModel product = products.get(position);
    ImageView imageViewProduct = (ImageView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProductImage);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductName);
    TextView textViewPriceFrom = (TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPriceFrom);
    TextView textViewPriceTo = (TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPriceTo);

    if (product.imageURL!=null) {
        Picasso.with(holder.mView.getContext()).load(imageUrl).into(imageViewProduct);
    }
    textViewPriceFrom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textViewPriceFrom.setPaintFlags(textViewPriceFrom.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

    if (product.enginePrice!=null && product.enginePrice.listPrice!=null && product.enginePrice.amountPrice!=null){
        if (product.enginePrice.listPrice>product.enginePrice.amountPrice){
            textViewPriceFrom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        textViewPriceFrom.setText(Util.priceStringFromDouble(product.enginePrice.listPrice));
        textViewPriceTo.setText(Util.priceStringFromDouble(product.enginePrice.amountPrice));
    }
    textViewName.setText(product.name+position);
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }
    });
}
```

I've noticed that only when the First TextView has the same value this bug occur. Bellow is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1)`android:layout_width="0dp"` this is probably the reason that it is not shown. change it to  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
 or assign it to any number of dp such as `android:layout_width="20dp"` and see if it is visible now.

2) Check if you dont forget the following statement that can make it invisible `textViewPriceFrom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

3) Check if there is a proper value provided for this textview. Basically it is not an empty string `Util.priceStringFromDouble(product.enginePrice.listPrice)`